# Not getting all entries of an attribute in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

In my `controller` I've this method:

```
public function code($code)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $instituteCodes = DB::table('institute_codes')->where(['code' => $code, 'institute_id' => Auth::id()]);
    if($instituteCodes->exists()){
        
        $claim = DB::table('code_claims')->where('institute_code_id', $instituteCodes->value('id'))->get();
        $allusers = collect($claim);
        $allusers->values()->all();
        $course =  Course::findOrFail($instituteCodes->value('course_id'));
        
        return view('institute.code', compact(['allusers', 'course']));
    }
}
```

`institute_codes` table

| id | code | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1 |
| 2 | ZXC | 5 |

`course` table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Python |
| 2 | Laravel |

I've a route which passes `$code` parameter to `public function code()` I'm getting same course data on using different codes in blade view but when I use `return $course` or `dd($course)` in controller it returns the the expected result i.e. different courses for different codes. But in blade I'm getting same courses. Any help will be appreciated.

This is happening!

[image: When code is ASDFG]

[image: When code is ZXCVBNM]

Why both codes are returning same course in blade and different courses(this is what I want) on using `dd` or `return`.

Edit 1

**Blade View**

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="fl-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="long-table-row">Email</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Enrolled On</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
            <th>Certificate</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($allusers as $item)
        <tr>
                
            <td class="long-table-row">
            {{ $item->user_email }}
            </td>
                
            <td class="uppercase">{{ $code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $course->c_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $course->language->name }}</td>
            <td>29/07/2022</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td><i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" style="font-size: 1.2vw; color: rgb(0, 200, 90);"></i></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm getting same `c_name` and `language name` for different codes.

Comment: If you are doing `return` or ` dd`, then your blade view is the issue... please, share the view and the full code as your questions is missing some info

Comment: @matiaslauriti I've edited the question and added the blade view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are iterating through the allusers but for course you are only picking the first course in the foreach loop of allusers.